# Plotting multiple y axis lines in a d3.js chart

Tags: d3.js

I am plotting a single line in d3.js using these arrays for the x and y axes:

```
    prob = ["0.93", "0.91", "0.89"];
    iml = ["0.005", "0.007", "0.0098"];
```

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/FrSs9/

How can I add another array to be plotted in the y axis, e.g:

```
    prob2 = ["0.89", "0.85", "0.5277"];
```

The x axis will always be the iml values.

Comment: Are you looking for a [multi-series line chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955)?

Comment: yes, but it's not clear how I need to extend the y.domain?

Comment: The extent of the domains is determined automatically from the data.

Comment: How should the data array be structured?

Comment: There's no set structure. If you have a look at the various examples for multi-series charts, you'll see that there are a variety of data formats. You may find the [NVD3 line chart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/line.html) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I figured it out: http://jsfiddle.net/5YEkq/